# Does tkx have a tagConfigure equivalent and a way to change text colors on a text widget?

Tags: tkx

Does  tkx have a tagConfigure equivalent and a way to change text colors on a text widget?

I have a tool I created years ago based on perl tk which I am trying to convert to tkx using ActivePerl 5.x and beyond.   I have made progress but one of the items I am stumped on is changing font colors in a text widget.  With tk I used tagConfigure.
    $txt->tagConfigure('normal', -font=>"Arial 10", -foreground=>"white");
    $txt->tagConfigure('bold', -font=>"Arial 10 bold", -foreground=>"white");
    $txt->tagConfigure('FC1', -font=>"Arial 10", -foreground=>"orange");
    ….
Then I used the insert function to append the text with the color I wanted.
    $txt->insert(‘end’,$TEXT,$COLOR);
It appears as if tkx uses “$txt->insert_end($TEXT);”,  but it doesn’t appear to allow you to change colors.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer.  This is the correct syntax for tkx:
    $txt->tag_configure('FC7', -font=>"Arial 10", -foreground=>"black", -background=>"white");
    $txt->insert_end("My message\n", "FC7");